# Mono / WCF: Cannot determine caller IP on Ubuntu

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, ubuntu, mono

I have a web service written in C# and I am trying to run it on Mono (Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.8.1 (Debian 2.10.8.1-1ubuntu2.2))

In the web service there is a helper function to determine the caller's ip address:

```
    public static System.Net.IPAddress GetCallerIP()
    {
        System.ServiceModel.OperationContext context = System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current;
        System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageProperties prop = context.IncomingMessageProperties;
        System.ServiceModel.Channels.RemoteEndpointMessageProperty callerEndpoint =
            prop[System.ServiceModel.Channels.RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as System.ServiceModel.Channels.RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;

        System.Net.IPAddress ip= System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(callerEndpoint.Address);
        return ip;
    }
```

On Windows, there are 6 properties in prop: `Via, httpRequest, System.ServiceModel.Channels.RemoteEndpointMessageProperty, UriTemplateMatchResults, UriMatched, HttpOperationName`

On Ubuntu, I only see 3 properties: `Via, httpRequest, Urimatched`

Therefore, my helper function cannot determine the caller's IP address when running on Ubuntu. What's wrong?

**Additional information**

Mono supports RemoteEndpointMessageProperty since 2.10.3, so I am pretty sure my version of Mono supports it.

Regarding RemoteEndpointMessageProperty, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.remoteendpointmessageproperty(v=vs.110).aspx) says the following in the Remarks section:

> The property is added to each incoming message to a Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) service through both the HTTP and TCP transports.
>
> The property is not present on messages received through either a named pipes or MSMQ transport.

I wonder if this relates to my issue? But how do I verify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*mono* is open source, as such you can always just look at the code and the commit history. Furthermore, you can even debug the runtime itself, for example in `monodevelop` by unchecking the "*Debug project code only; do not step into framework code*" option.

From a quick glance, for HTTP POST messages the relevant property is being set since commit [fd8ae35d](https://github.com/mono/mono/commit/fd8ae35df0996a4729c48c43df9b8506b90b685e). Although this predates the release of `2.10.8.1`, unfortunately that version came from a different branch and hence doesn't include this change. The first version containing it is `2.11.0`.

The 2.x series is very old by now, upgrading is a good idea anyway.

Comment: I have upgraded to Mono 3.4.0 and MonoDevelop 4.0 and updated my project's target framework to Mono / .NET 4.5 but am still observing the exact same behavior.

Comment: I couldn't even get a simple WCF webservice running for testing so you are ahead of me. Post complete project or use the sources and the debugger to find out where the error is.